# ActiveAdmin - changing namespace and links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using activeadmin and my namespace is 'admin'

I want to change the namespace to 'foo' so in initializers/activeadmin.rb I add this line:

```
config.default_namespace = :foo
```

But I have about 30 admin_xxxx_path (e.g admin_order_path) in my code which now I need to change to foo_xxxx_path.

Is there a non-manual way of updating those links?

Comment: What's your reason for the change?  I ask because you could just leave the namespace but set a path so it would use /foo but go to the admin controllers

Comment: The reason is security. I don't want the admin path to be 'admin'. How do I implement your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, in ActiveAdmin I have no idea because I don't use it but in standard rails you can do:

```
namespace :admin, :path => "foo" do
  #entries
end
```

Comment: Can you give an example for an entry?

Comment: Just whatever your resources are `resources :posts`

Comment: The only line seem relevant in routes.rb is ActiveAdmin.routes(self).
I've tried to put it inside the namespace declaration but it gave me routes like /foo/admin/orders/new(.:format) => admin/admin/orders#new

Comment: You'll have to look into the documentation for ActiveAdmin to see if it allows you to do this.

Comment: Care to explain why?  I agree it'd be better just to change all the references